# Definition: $L^\infty$ norm of a tensor

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

My question is regarding the definition of the $L^\infty$ norm of a tensor. For simplicity, say we are working with a manifold $(M,g)$ and $K\subset M$ is a compact. For instance, for the metric $g$, how is its $L^\infty$ norm over $K$ defined, i.e. how is $||g||_{L^\infty (K)}$ defined?

This could be done if we define a coordinate system $(x^i)_{i=1}^n$. In fact, we could define
$$||g||_{L^\infty(K)}=sup_{x\in K,1\leq i,j\leq n}|g_{ij}(x)|.$$

However, according to this definition, the $L^\infty$ norm is coordinate dependent. Is the a standard way in which the $L^\infty$ norm of a tensor is defined?
Thanks

Comment: Your understanding is correct. Given a Riemannian metric, it is possible to define the $L^\infty$ norm of a tensor. However, the only way to define the $L^\infty$ norm of the metric tensor itself, it is necessary to do this with respect to either local coordinates, as you describe, or with respect to another Riemannian metric.

Answer (score 1):

First linear algebra: an inner product on a vector space $V$ induces one on the various tensor spaces $T^r_s(V)$ (or exterior powers etc). So, now given this inner product, you have a norm $\|\cdot\|_{T^r_s(V)}$ on the various tensor spaces. A Riemannian metric on a manifold does this on each tangent space. So, if you have a tensor field $F$ (a-priori not smooth), you have at each point $x\in M$, a tensor $F(x)$, and hence its norm $\|F(x)\|$. Take the (essential-)supremum of this over your set of interest (essential supremum makes sense because a Riemannian metric induces a natural measure $\lambda_g$ on $M$, often denoted $dV_g$).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am familiar with the linear algebra setting, what is unclear to me is how you actually define the norm, using your notation $||F(x)||$. It's clear to me how to get the $L^\infty$ from there. For instance at a point $x$ in $M$, the metric is a bilinear form $g:T_xM\times T_xM\to \mathbb{R}_+$. How do you define $||T(x)||$ in this space?

Comment: @zoji_ed do you agree $g(x)$ is an inner product on $T_xM$? So, by the linear algebraic preliminaries, which you said you’re familiar with, we know it induces a norm $\|\cdot\|_{T^r_s(T_xM)}$ for all possible $r,s$. Literally, we’re just applying the same arguments to $V=T_xM$.